# Google App Engine: Serve static webpage in a subdirectory

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My file structure:
Root directory:
css [dir]
js [dir]
img [dir]
font [dir]
khikhi [dir]
app.yaml
index.html
index.yaml
khikhi directory:
css [dir]
js [dir]
img [dir]
index.html

App.yaml:

```
application: mywebsitesname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(svg|ttf|woff|woff2|gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(svg|ttf|woff|woff2|gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Main.py:

```
# Copyright 2012 Digital Inspiration
# http://www.labnol.org/

import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'
    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

Currently, the index.html in my root directory is being served when I go to mydomain.com, but I want /khikhi/index.html to be served as well when I go to mydomain.com/khikhi/ or mydomain.com/khikhi. What changes should I make to the files so make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add, as the very first entry right under `handlers:`...:

```
- url: /khihi
  static_files: khikhi/index.html
```

There may be other issues with this whole arrangement, e.g it's hard to fathom what you mean by

> when I go to mydomain.com/khikhi or mydomain.com/khikhi

"when I go to SOMETHING or **EXACTLY** the same thing" -- what do you mean by **or** in this context, pray?!  But, I'm trying to just directly answer your direct question (so I'm taking "A or A" as identically equal to "A", as it would be in normal logic or any programming language -- even though a Gricean implicature analysis [*] suggests your Q **must** have a problem on that bit!-).

[*] the core foundation of **pragmatics** as a key part of linguistics, named in honor of H. P. Grice, refers to meaning suggested in an utterance though not actually expressed, based on Grice's "Maxims" -- e.g, the utterance "I never curse at SO posters asking ambiguous questions on weekends" is factually true and does **not** afford an implication that I may actually curse at them on weekdays -- but the Gricean implicature is that indeed I may, or else, why would I bother qualifying the non-cursing assertion by that "on weekends" restriction?-)

Comment: So sorry, forgot to add a slash on one of those links.

I was getting a 'Missing "upload" attribute for URL "/khikhi".' error when I try to run it. So, I added a "upload: khikhi/index.html" attribute to the handler. Also it doesn't work when I go to mydomain.com/khikhi/. And none of files from my khikhi/css, khikhi/js, and khikhi/img are getting loaded.

Comment: Fixed everything. Changed the link tags to absolute paths, added a couple of other things in the app.yaml file! Thank you! :)

Comment: @UmangGalaiya, you're welcome!  Hope I can get at **accept** from you (click the checkmark-shaped outline to the left of my answer...!-)